# Frame json-ld document to append children

Tags: json, node.js, json-ld

I'm trying to create a frame to include every children inside an array, so Detail (see the example) must contain all the other nodes inside itself.

This is an example of the data I'm using, in expanded JSON-LD:

```
[
 {
   "@id": "A",
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Person": [
     {
       "@value": "101023",
       "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
     }
   ],
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Detail": [
     {
       "@id": "_:g70157685738360"
     },
     {
       "@id": "_:g70157685722960"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "@id": "_:g70157685722960",
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Deuda": [
     {
       "@value": "OFICINA"
     }
   ],
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Detalle": [
     {
       "@value": "100"
       "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "@id": "_:g70157685738360",
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Deuda": [
     {
       "@value": "3573.04",
       "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal"
     }
   ],
   "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#Detalle": [
     {
       "@value": "AUTOMOTORES"
     }
   ]
 }
```

]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following frame does that (and sets the default vocabulary to `http://ontology.ayvu.net/#` so that those long URLs disappear):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#"
  },
  "Detail": {}
}
```

The frame ensures that the top-level object contains a `Detail` property so that you get the right root object. The children are then automatically moved down the JSON tree.

The result will look as follows:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://ontology.ayvu.net/#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "A",
      "Person": {
        "@value": "101023"
        "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",
      },
      "Detail": [
        {
          "@id": "_:b0",
          "Detalle": "AUTOMOTORES",
          "Deuda": {
            "@value": "3573.04"
            "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal",
          }
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:b1",
          "Detalle": {
            "@value": "100"
            "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal",
          },
          "Deuda": "OFICINA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Or live in the JSON-LD playground: http://tinyurl.com/q844vkd

Comment: What if one deals with an arbitrary graph represented in JSON-LD and just wants it framed by the top-level object, whichever that is?